# Print data from Alamofire request, swift

Tags: swift, xcode, get, alamofire

I made this request:

```
func AlamofireGetCode()
{
    let username: String = searchTextField.text!
    var url:String!
    url = "https:// ... "

    AF.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                debugPrint(response)
            case .failure(let error):
                fatalError("\(error)")
            }
        }
}
```

And I'm getting this response with different fields:

```
[Result]: success({
"incomplete_results" = 0;
items =     (
            {
        "username" = " ... "
        ...
```

How do I get some specific field like "username" in Swift? 
I would like to have all the username of all the user and store them, could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a type to parse the JSON response into. Using a site like quicktype.io can generate one from your JSON, but any `Decodable` type will do. Then you can use Alamofire's `responseDecodable` handler to parse your response.

```swift
AF.request(url).responseDecodable(of: TypeToParse.self) { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your response was 100% what I was looking for.

Could I ask one more? What if a want to access one specific field like "username" in another view? I declared Struct out of my class, so it is accessible in the other view, but I can't get the username data

Comment: My struct is something like this ***struct UserInfo: Codable {
    let totalCount: Int
    let incompleteResults: Bool
    let items: [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalCount = "total_count"
        case incompleteResults = "incomplete_results"
        case items
    }
}

// MARK: - Item
struct Item: Codable {
    let login: String
    let id: Int
    let avatarURL: String


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case login, id
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
    }
}***

Comment: Most likely you'd need to use a completion handler to pass the received and parsed response back to the other screens that need it. I suggest you look into those.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your response in https://jsonparseronline.com/ to see the structure of the object. It will show you all the keys and values that you can access using subscripts.